# Writing a VS extension and want to get the fully qualified type of the C# text in the editor I am mousing over

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn, visual-studio-extensions, roslyn-code-analysis

1. I have a working VS extension in VS 2019
2. I trigger events when mousing over text in the editor (in this case, C#)
3. My extension receives an EventArgs (actually MouseHoverEventArgs), which I can use to access the textPosition, and can get the line I'm mousing over as text

Question: How do I get this with syntactic context? i.e. a set of tokens for the line / area I am mousing over, in a way that I can generate the fully scoped name of the type?  i.e. how do I hook into the syntactic content of the editor's live evaluation of the syntax of the file?

I'd want something like:
`private string GetTypeOfMousedOverToken(EventArgs e)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to get syntactic context:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.SnapshotPoint caretPosition = textView.Caret.Position.BufferPosition;
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document document = caretPosition.Snapshot.GetOpenDocumentInCurrentContextWithChanges();
document.GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result.FindToken(caretPosition)
```

See https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/commands.html#CreateTypedVariable for a complete example.

Comment: required usings: `using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;`

Comment: making it specific to the context (MouseHoverEventArgs e):
```
var document = e.View.TextSnapshot.GetOpenDocumentInCurrentContextWithChanges();
var token = document.GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result.FindToken(e.Position);
```